# Unity3d - Failed to compile resources with the following parameters (WINDOWS)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my project in Unity3d to an android app and it gives me this Error:

> Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
>   -bootclasspath "C:/Users/itayt/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\itayt\Documents\ShowTest\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com\wikitude\unity\R.java"

I saw a solution on the web but it was for Ubuntu, and I'm using Windows.
things I already tried:

-adding the Java path in the Environment Variables
-downloading the latest Jdk and Jre

any solutions to a Windows user?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else who ends up here: As of Unity 2017, Unity is incompatible with JDK 9. You need to continue to use JDK 1.8 for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather hard to give a straight answer because the information provided too generic, but let's give it a shot:

First of all, add JDK installation to PATH. Something like C:\Program Files\Java\JDK version\bin

If you can run javac in CMD without giving full path to it then you're good

Then verify that JDK_HOME variable is set correctly too

Also, make sure that the target SDK tools, build-tools and SDK platform are installed. Just in case, run Android SDK manager and update/install components of the same build version as you set in Unity's build settings. Android compiler is quite sensitive to these matters

Validate the errors and build messages in the Editor log
The Editor log can be brought up through the Open Editor Log button in Unity’s Console window. Alternatively, check this location:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log - usually it will give a bit more information

Comment: few questions:
1) what do you mean by adding jdk installation to PATH?
2)how do i know the JDK_HOME path is set correctly?

Comment: In Environmental Variables there's a variable called PATH. Add path to JDK's bin folder at the end of it preceding with ;

Quick guude: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path


JAVA_HOME points to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02