# Unity3D build error : Failed to compile resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I use UltimateMobile plugin and uniwebview plugin ,maybe they are conflict.
when I build ,Unity3d console say :

```
    Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
    -bootclasspath 
    "C:/Program Files/Java/android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -d 
    "C:\Game\3drq\superblocks\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" 
    -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 
    "android\support\v4\Manifest.java" 
    "android\support\v4\R.java"             
    "com\cheerflame\superblocks\Manifest.java" 
    "com\cheerflame\superblocks\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\R.java"    
    "com\google\android\gms\ads\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\ads\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\ads\impl\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\ads\impl\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\analytics\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\analytics\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\appinvite\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\appinvite\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\auth\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\auth\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\auth\api\Manifest.java"
    "com\google\android\gms\auth\api\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\base\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\base\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\drive\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\drive\R.java" 
     "com\google\android\gms\games\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\games\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\gcm\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\gcm\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\iid\Manifest.java"
     "com\google\android\gms\iid\R.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\plus\Manifest.java" 
    "com\google\android\gms\plus\R.java" 
    "com\stansassets\androidnative\Manifest.java"       
    "com\stansassets\androidnative\R.java"
     "com\stansassets\billing\Manifest.java" 
      "com\stansassets\billing\R.java" 
    "com\stansassets\googleplay\Manifest.java" 
    "com\stansassets\googleplay\R.java" 
    "com\stansassets\mnp\Manifest.java" 
    "com\stansassets\mnp\R.java" 
    "com\stansassets\social\Manifest.java" 
    "com\stansassets\social\R.java"
     ����: C:\Program Files\Java\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar(java/lang/Object.class): 

���汾 52 �� 51 ��, �˱�����֧�����µ����汾�����������˱�������

����: C:\Program Files\Java\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar(java/lang/String.class): 
���汾 52 �� 51 ��, �˱�����֧�����µ����汾��
    ���������˱�������
     ����: 
C:\Program Files\Java\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\android.jar(java/lang/AutoCloseable.class): 
���汾 52 �� 51 ��, �˱�����֧�����µ����汾��
                      ���������˱�������
                    3 ������
```

why there are so many messy code? 
I build the project in another computer,it's fine and can be built to a apk file.
I don't understand ,please help me. thanks !

Comment: In the future, you should also try searching online for key parts of your error message and explain in your question what you've found and what solutions you've attempted. An appropriate search query would be something like: "Unity Failed to compile resources with the following parameters: -bootclasspath"

Comment: I‘m sorry, I really want to talk about more,but my English is poor. I'm Chinese .I'm sorry for the information is too few. I have reinstall the android sdk with sdk manager from 25 to 27. The most strange thing is I put my project with git , my another computer can build well with the same source code

Comment: Are both computers using the same SDK version? Did you read the answer I posted below? Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding. If you're using 27, you should try using 25 (the same version as your other computer that works).

Comment: I have read the below answer you posted. My plugin need 26 at least. So my two computer use 27 . And the working well computer' s jdk is jdk1.8.0161, it's the same as the bad working computer. I have also reinstall the unity3d programer at the bad working computer.

Comment: I see, sorry for misunderstanding. I'm out of ideas at the moment, but [the other answer to the SO post I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152088/5170571) may help you debug the issue further.

Comment: Forget to say thanks, thank you for answer my question.  Do you  see the messy code just like black cube , what cause them ?

Comment: No problem, I hope you are able to fix your issue. I revised my answer below to explain what the messy error messages with black cubes could mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade to JDK 8. According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522136/5170571) which has a similar error message to your question:

> As of Unity 2017, Unity is incompatible with JDK 9. You need to
>   continue to use JDK 1.8 for the time being.

(Note: there is also an [active issue on the Unity Issue Tracker for JDK 9](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-builds-fail-with-java-9-jdk-and-unable-to-list-target-platforms-error) that seems to be related. It's not the exact same error message, but others are commenting there with your error message as well.)

*(EDIT: The question's error message shows "android-27", so this may not be the actual solution. I'm leaving this here for now as a solution attempt, and because one of the most common reasons for this error message, in general, is the JDK version.)*

---

(Also, to give one possible explanation for "why there are so many messy code?": the little question mark with the black box has to do with strings and character encodings. It likely has something to do with the asker's computer language being set to another language like Chinese. I'm not sure about the exact cause in this case, but see [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) for more background information about the black box question mark characters:

> And in fact now that you’re thinking of things in terms of platonic
>   ideal letters which are represented by Unicode code points, those
>   unicode code points can be encoded in any old-school encoding scheme,
>   too! For example, you could encode the Unicode string for Hello
>   (U+0048 U+0065 U+006C U+006C U+006F) in ASCII, or the old OEM Greek
>   Encoding, or the Hebrew ANSI Encoding, or any of several hundred
>   encodings that have been invented so far, with one catch: some of the
>   letters might not show up! If there’s no equivalent for the Unicode
>   code point you’re trying to represent in the encoding you’re trying to
>   represent it in, you usually get a little question mark: ? or, if
>   you’re really good, a box. Which did you get? -> �

Comment: Thanks,but my two computer all Chinese. I will copy the SDK and JDK from the good working computer to the bad tomorrow. The one in office the other in my home. After this ,I come back here.